# Spring Jpa LessThanEqual for postgres timestamp field

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have field effective_startdate in my Entity class.

```
@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "effective_startdate", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE")
private Date effectiveStartdate;
```

Which i wanted to use in my Jpa repository class for filtering into my getmapping method for further use:

```
List<PoJoObject> findByEffectiveStartdateLessThanEqual(Date date);
```

For this entire operation my backend db is postgres and the same field there is having type as TIMESTAMP.

Would anyone can help me to get the expected format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") response from the my getmapping call.

I am totally new to this and did not know how the Spring is internally dealing with Date and serializing/deserializing and comparing with postgres db.

Note:

- using java.util.Date in java code.
- postgres effective_startdate output look like this:

> 2019-09-19 18:28:23.012

- response format for the same field is coming as:

> "effectiveStartdate": "2019-07-30T04:37:55.000+0000"

Comment: I rolled back your changes to the question, because it turns a question into a completely different one.
Instead of changing the question please accept the answer that solved your original question and create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the JsonFormat annotation to the effectiveStartdate:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "effective_startdate", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE")
private Date effectiveStartdate;
```

Btw. the @Basic annotation is not necessary and the column name is also superfluous because this is how Hibernate translates _ to camelCase.

Comment: I used underscore because on postgres side it i use camelCase pattern for columns it automatically flatten out to all lower case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, from the response I applied the pattern you suggested and it is working absolutely fine. But my query result is not matched with HH:mm:ss.SSS passed valued just yyyy-MM-dd is fulling the given condition. I updated the question as well for more clarity.